# How to use boost c++ library in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, boost, objective-c++

I am successfully add boost framework in my Xcode and also run some boost function but i want to get boost version.

here is some prototype of my snippet :

```
#import "ViewController.h"
using namespace std;
using namespace boost;

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

string str1(" hello world! ");
to_upper(str1);  // str1 == " HELLO WORLD! "
trim(str1);      // str1 == "HELLO WORLD!"

string str2=
to_lower_copy(
              ireplace_first_copy(
                                  str1,"hello","goodbye")); // str2 == "goodbye world!"
cout<<str2;

}
```

Comment: Just a quick note: That's not pure C++, it is Objective-C++.

Comment: Wait - by "get boost version", do you mean you want to find out what version of Boost is currently installed (for example so you can use different code that works with an older version of Boost), or do you mean you want to run code that does this using boost, as opposed to using NSString and other Objective-C commands? In my answer I assumed the second, but it just occurred to me you may be asking the first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short answer**

Your file probably has a `.m` suffix instead of the `.mm` suffix your code needs to use C++ commands in an otherwise Objective-C app. You also need to include the requisite boost headers. If you can tell us what error messages you are getting, or what problem you're trying to solve, that might help.

**Long answer**

I think you're a bit confused about the difference between an IDE and a programming language. Xcode is an IDE. That is, an app on your computer that can take a bunch of files and combine them into a new app.

C++ is one of the programming languages that you can use to define the *behaviours* of your app (C++ files usually have names ending in .cp or .cpp). In addition to behaviours, you can also provide image files and sound files to be used by these behaviours etc.

Usually, people use Objective-C (another programming language) to define behaviours for Mac applications (Those files end in .m instead).

What you are doing above is writing C++ code in an Objective-C source file, which the computer can't understand (Just like most people would have problems if I started using Japanese words in an English sentence.

However, Apple know people often use C++, so just like you can agree with friends that since you both speak English and Japanese, you'll just mix the words, you can tell Xcode that a certain file will mix C++ and Objective-C. This is done by inventing a new language, Objective-C++, which Xcode knows to use when you give your files the suffix ".mm".